# How to call a function from RaisedButton onPressed - Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, event-handling, flutter-onpressed

I'm new to flutter, and I have a pretty simple question that's annoying me by the past couple days. I have this simple Raised Button:

```
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextField(),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Clicou"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _changeText();
                  }),
              MyText(myText)
            ],
          )
```

There I call `onPressed` _changeText(), a simple function that changes a label on screen, however checkout that I'm calling my method using  `()` at the end.
Well, I was learning from an youtube video where the guys says I should pass my method without `()`, but when I try this way the button simply do not work.

So, my question in fact is: How should I call methods on `onPressed` or any other event listners?

Here goes my code file:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// entry point for the app,
// the => operator is shorthand for {} when there is only one line of code
void main() => runApp(Root());

class Root extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyApp();
  }
}

// the root widget of our application
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String myText = "";

  void _changeText() {
    print("TESETSSS");

    setState(() {
      myText = "batman";
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Building layouts"),
          ),
          body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TextField(),
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Clicou"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _changeText();
                      }),
                  MyText(myText)
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}


class MyText extends StatelessWidget {

  final String myText;

  MyText(this.myText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(myText);
  }

}
```

Comment: As what I understood to your problem, you just want to reference a function to `onPressed`. If so, `onPressed: _changeText` will solve your concern.

Comment: That's the problem, when I reference the function, the button stops working, however if I call the function it start working again.

Comment: Weird... I tried your code and used the function reference approach, it  works fine.

Comment: @rickimaru I figure out what I was doing wrong, I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

After some time, I figure out what was wrong.
In this piece of code I'm creating an anonymous function, and them calling my change text funcion inside it, so the reference is doing nothing.

```
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Clicou"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _changeText();
                      }),
```

The correct approach would be:

```
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Clicou"),
                      onPressed: _changeText
                      ),
```

In this second case, I'm assinging to "onPressed" the reference to _changeText;
And there is it, works like a charm.